# jquery loop over fields to get id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to loop over some date picker fields and get the id of each input.  But the alert is displaying as blank.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('.input-group.date'), function() {
        alert(this.id);
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

HTML/Ruby code looks like:

```
<tr>
        <td class="label-date">Start Date</td>
        <td colspan="2"><%= date_select(f, :agent_start_on, {class: "form-control date"}) %></td>
        <td colspan="2"><%= date_select(f, :sales_start_on, {class: "form-control date"}) %></td>
        <td colspan="2"><%= date_select(f, :manager_start_on, {class: "form-control date"}) %></td>
        <td colspan="2"><%= date_select(f, :ceo_start_on, {class: "form-control date"}) %></td>
        <td colspan="2"><%= date_select(f, :region_start_on, {class: "form-control date"}) %></td>
      </tr>
```

Whn I inspect the element in Chrome (here is the first one):

```
<div class="form-group"><div class="input-group date  "><input class="form-control" id="loa_item_agency_effective_on" name="loa_item[agent_start_on]" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" value=""><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div>
```

Ultimately I want to loop over each and get its value.  But I guess I need the id to do this as it looks like the id is generated at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get id of `div` instead of `input` inside it. use below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input-group.date').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this).find('input.form-control');
        alert($input.attr('id'));
        alert($input.val());
    });
});
```

**EDIT** :
   on change of input you can use below code

This code will give you id of changed datepicker.

```
$(document).on('change','.input-group.date input.form-control',function() {
        var $input = $(this);
       alert($input.attr('id'));
        alert($input.val());
    });
```

To get id of all datepicker when any of the datepicker changed then use below code

```
$(document).on('change','.input-group.date input.form-control',function() {
       $('.input-group.date').each(function() {
            var $input = $(this).find('input.form-control');
            alert($input.attr('id'));
            alert($input.val());
        });
    });
```

Comment: this works and will mark as answer - do you know how to only do this when the input has changed?  .each.change?  Its really a datepicker that when they select a date I want this code to execute

Answer (score 0):

Your each method is wrong. Actually it comes like

```
$('.input-group.date').each(function() {
  alert($(this).find('input[type=text]').val()); // get the input value
  alert($(this).find('input[type=text]').attr('id')); // get the input id
});
```

Comment: I get the same result - the ids are blanks

Comment: alert(this.attr('id'));

Comment: I want to know when the value has changed, and what input id was changed.  So I can change another one using Jquery,  So like a datepicker, when the user selects the date, I want to change the value of another datepicker.  I guess I need to get the IDs

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the `each()` function on an element for example:

```
$('#input').each( function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know which input is the one you want and you must iterate through them, you can get all those values with this function. Remember to put the form selector correctly.
With this you can have the value no matter the id, but if you want the id you can call .attr('id').

```
_getFormData = function() {
  var values = {};
  $('#myForm :input').each(function() {
    this.name ? values[this.name] = $(this).val() : ""; // we don't need the submit button
    console.log(this.id); // CHECK THIS.
  });
  return values;
}
```

Check if the input has a value, from console in the browser first, and you will have a better chance to know what is going on. In the browser press F12, in console tab put this:

```
var el = $("#loa_item_agency_effective_on");
console.log(el.val())
```

Maybe you have parents and childrens and you need to get the info in some other element.

Hope it helps.